# Typescript intellisense for object properties in visual studio not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, intellisense

In my typescript file, I have the following code:

```
var Application = Application || {};

Application.Constants = angular.module("application.constants", []);
Application.Services = angular.module("application.services", []);
Application.Controllers = angular.module("application.controllers", []);
Application.Filters = angular.module("application.filters", []);
Application.Directives = angular.module("application.directives", []);


angular.module("application", ["application.filters", "application.services", "application.directives", "application.constants", "application.controllers"]);
```

Intellisense isn't showing up, as you can see:

[image: Typescript not showing]

But in the actual generated javascript, which is identical... I get intellisense just fine from visual studio as you can see:

[image: Typescript Working]

Is there a reason that visual studio typescript wouldn't be able to figure this out?

Do I seriously have to create my own type, like this, to be able to get intellisense for properties on an object?

[image: Fix by creating an interface]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript does not infer types from assignments. To think about why, consider the following code:

```
var player = {};
player.intelligence = 10;
player.wisdom = 30;

if(desiredClass === "Barbarian") {
    player.strenght = 100;
} else {
    player.strength = 20;
}
```

There would be no way to issue an error here, despite it being one of the most common kinds of typos in programs.

Comment: So is what I did in the last image the proper thing to do in this case, then?

Comment: I don't follow how your example explains why `TypeScript does not infer types from assignments.`